# Why does the Integer Type Conversion of sin^2(a)+cos^2(a) return 0 instead of 1?

Tags: c, trigonometry, typecasting-operator

When I'm printing  sin(theta) * sin(theta)+ cos(theta)* cos(theta), it's coming out to be equal to 1.000000. But when I'm typecasting the same expression into int, the result comes out to be 0.

```
 #include< stdio.h >
 #include< math.h >
 #define PI acos(-1)
 int main()
 {
     float theta;
     printf("Theta : ");
     scanf("%f",&theta);
     theta=theta*PI/180;
     printf("%f\n",sin(theta)*sin(theta)+cos(theta)*cos(theta));
     printf("%d\n",(int)(sin(theta)*sin(theta)+cos(theta)*cos(theta)));
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Try `%0.30f`....

Comment: Many of the transcendental functions are actually evaluated with polynomials, Taylor series expansions, range reduction, etc. Even the most careful implementations can only at best return a value rounded to the nearest representable floating point value.

Comment: Note that rounding errors are already present in the *inputs* to `sin()` and `cos()` which further exacerbates the issue mentioned by @BrettHale. Check if your platform offers functions `sinpi()` and `cospi()` and if so, use them to minimize this component of the overall error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you cast a floating-point number to an integer, it just drops all digits after the decimal-point.  Your 1.0000 is probably actually something closer to 0.99999999999999 due rounding errors caused by the fact that only a finite number of bits are used to represent a number.  All floating-point numbers are subject to this issue.  Therefore never expect an EXACT answer when dealing with floating-point numbers.

Your display is rounding the result to 1.00000.  However, when 0.999999 is casted to an int, it drops the decimals and so it ends up with 0.

You can use the `round()` or `roundf()` function to ensure it is rounded as you expected. [(reference)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/)

```
 #include< stdio.h >
 #include< math.h >
 #define PI acos(-1)

 int main()
 {
     float theta;
     printf("Theta : ");
     scanf("%f",&theta);
     theta=theta*PI/180;

     float resultf  = sin(theta)*sin(theta)+cos(theta)*cos(theta);
     int   resulti  = roundf(resultf);
     printf("%f\n",resultf);
     printf("%d\n",resulti);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks.